# layout_below doesn't work in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

In the below XML layout, I am trying to make each value(accXValue, accYValue,accZValue) appear to the right of their respective label as shown below in the code.

At runtime, all the values are placed over each other to the right of the (tv_accX_label), all the values overlap each other and located in one position despite the fact that I specified the attributes `layout_below`.

Please let me know what I am missing.

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accX_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Acc[X]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accX_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_accX_label"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accY_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accX_label"
    android:text="Acc[Y]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accY_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_accY_label"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accZ_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accY_label"
    android:text="Acc[Z]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accZ_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_accZ_label"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accZ_label"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="send to frag_2"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*valueY* is actually displayed to the `rightOf` *labelY*. You just didn't provide a `below` attribute on *values*, that's why they're stacking on top of each other. This is how:

valueY:

```
<TextView
    android:text="RIGHT"
    android:id="@+id/tv_accY_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accX_value"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_accY_label"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_accY_label"/>
```

valueZ:

```
<TextView
    android:text="BELOW"
    android:id="@+id/tv_accZ_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accY_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_accY_label"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_accY_label"/>
```

Comment: should i only skip it in "layout-below" and when using "layout_rightOf" i should not skip it?

Comment: ok now i skipped the + from layout_below and layout_rightOf. but still they over lap

Comment: @rmaik sorry, I was wrong. + sign is okay. Your problem is in not providing a `below` attribute, as in my updated answer.